# Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") in R-Markdown

Tags: r, installation, r-markdown, knitr

While knitting my Rmarkdown, I'm receiving error as:

> Error in contrib.url(repos,"source"):  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
> Calls:  ... eval_with_user_handles -> eval-> install.packages -> contrib.url
> Exclusion halted

I installed these packages:

```
install.packages("RNOmni")
library(RNOmni)
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("palmerpenguins") 
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("dagitty")
install.packages("ggdag")
library(dagitty)
library(ggdag)
```

not sure what's wrong with R.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do that for every single one so it would go like this:

```
install.packages("RNOmni", , repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(RNOmni)
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library("palmerpenguins") 
install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("dagitty", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("ggdag", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(dagitty)
library(ggdag)
```

Comment: A more concise way is to install them all with one commend. `install.packages(c("RNOmni", "ggplot2", "palmerpenguins"), repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`